# Raspberry pi pico W - code don't run when battery powered

Tags: battery, micropython, pi-pico-w

I've a Raspberry pi pico W and I the following code works with Thonny IDE but not when battery powered. The pico work with my battery because a simple code which turn on and off the pico led works great. Why is my code not working when the pico is powered in USB with a powerbank ?

My code:

```
from time import sleep, localtime
from picozero import DigitalOutputDevice, DigitalInputDevice, pico_led
import time
import network
import socket
from machine import Pin
import uasyncio as asyncio
import traceback
import sys

# Initialisation des variables
A=2
B=3
C=4
D=5
PIN_OPEN=28
PIN_CLOSE=27
time = 0.001

h_close = 16
m_close = 06
s_close = 20
# Definition des broches
pin_a = DigitalOutputDevice(A)
pin_b = DigitalOutputDevice(B)
pin_c = DigitalOutputDevice(C)
pin_d = DigitalOutputDevice(D)
btn_open = DigitalInputDevice(PIN_OPEN)
btn_close = DigitalInputDevice(PIN_CLOSE)
pico_led.on()
# Definition des etapes des moteurs
def Step1():
    pin_d.on()
    sleep (time)
    pin_d.off()
def Step2():
    pin_d.on()
    pin_c.on()
    sleep (time)
    pin_d.off()
    pin_c.off()
def Step3():
    pin_c.on()
    sleep (time)
    pin_c.off()
def Step4():
    pin_b.on()
    pin_c.on()
    sleep (time)
    pin_b.off()
    pin_c.off()
def Step5():
    pin_b.on()
    sleep (time)
    pin_b.off()
def Step6():
    pin_a.on()
    pin_b.on()
    sleep (time)
    pin_a.off()
    pin_b.off()
def Step7():
    pin_a.on()
    sleep (time)
    pin_a.off()
def Step8():
    pin_d.on()
    pin_a.on()
    sleep (time)
    pin_d.off()
    pin_a.off()

# Boutons
def button_open():
    if btn_open.is_active:
        print("btn open")
        for i in range (512):
            Step1()
            Step2()
            Step3()
            Step4()
            Step5()
            Step6()
            Step7()
            Step8()
        pin_a.off()
        pin_b.off()
        pin_c.off()
        pin_d.off()
        
def button_close():
    if btn_close.is_active:
        print("btn close")
        for i in range (512):
            Step8()
            Step7()
            Step6()
            Step5()
            Step4()
            Step3()
            Step2()
            Step1()
        pin_a.off()
        pin_b.off()
        pin_c.off()
        pin_d.off()

# Internet
led = Pin(15, Pin.OUT)
onboard = Pin("LED", Pin.OUT, value=0)

ssid = 'SFR-e670_2GEXT'
password = 'QY9L7AKJMDU4'

html = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> <title>Pico W</title> </head>
    <body> <h1>Pico W</h1>
        <p>%s</p>
        <p><a href="./on">Allumer la led</a></p>
        <p><a href="./off">Eteindre la led</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
"""

wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)

def connect_to_network():
    wlan.active(True)
    wlan.config(pm = 0xa11140) # Disable power-save mode
    wlan.connect(ssid, password)

    max_wait = 10
    while max_wait > 0:
        if wlan.status() < 0 or wlan.status() >= 3:
            break
        max_wait -= 1
        print('waiting for connection...')
        time.sleep(1)

    if wlan.status() != 3:
        raise RuntimeError('network connection failed')
    else:
        print('connected')
        status = wlan.ifconfig()
        print('ip = ' + status[0])

async def serve_client(reader, writer):
    print("Client connected")
    request_line = await reader.readline()
    print("Request:", request_line)
    # We are not interested in HTTP request headers, skip them
    while await reader.readline() != b"\r\n":
        pass

    request = str(request_line)
    led_on = request.find('/on')
    led_off = request.find('/off')
    print( 'led on = ' + str(led_on))
    print( 'led off = ' + str(led_off))

    stateis = ""
    if led_on == 6:
        print("led on")
        pico_led.on()
        stateis = "LED is ON"

    if led_off == 6:
        print("led off")
        pico_led.off()
        stateis = "LED is OFF"

    response = html % stateis
    writer.write('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\n\r\n')
    writer.write(response)

    await writer.drain()
    await writer.wait_closed()
    print("Client disconnected")

async def main():
    print('Connecting to Network...')
    connect_to_network()

    print('Setting up webserver...')
    asyncio.create_task(asyncio.start_server(serve_client, "0.0.0.0", 80))
    print('Working.')
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        button_open()
        button_close()

try:
    asyncio.run(main())
finally:
    asyncio.new_event_loop()
```

Thank you for reading my post :)

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 0):

I've spotted a couple of issues.

You are using 'import time', then setting 'time = 0.001', overwriting the time object. If the Pico does not connect to your wifi on the first attempt then 'time.sleep(1)' will fail.

You also only attempt 10 times to connect to the network. You could add something like flash the onboard led twice for a successful connection and flash 4 times for a failed connection.

I tested these changes on a battery bank, failed to connect on first power up - got 4 flashes, worked on 2nd power up - got 2 flashes. Web page worked as expected.